# PostgreSQL won't allow remote connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My Postgres installation won't allow me to connect remotely.
I set the *listen_addresses* field in the *postgresql.conf* to '*' and added the line

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

to *pg_hba.conf*, restarted the database and tried

```
psql dbname uname -h 127.0.0.1
```

I always get

> Password authentication failed for user "uname"

(also when just setting

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32               md5
```

in hba or testing from a remote host).

I can't find any more configurations or suggestions to fix this. I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 on Ubuntu 15.04 (installed from the repository). Has anyone a suggestion on what to try next? Or am I missing something?

Comment: did you try to connect to this remote database using pgadmin

Comment: Wrong password? Not connecting to the database you think you are?

Comment: @haceneabdessamed pgadmin gives me the same error: `Password authentication failed for user "uname"`

Comment: @CraigRinger I can connect locally with the database with the same user and password (using `pgsql dbname uname` on the houst where postgres runs), I have the according rule in pg_hba.conf `local all all  md5`

Comment: Does psql ask for the password on the terminal or do you get the error message without any interaction?

Comment: Can you log in via socket? (`psql dbname uname -h ''`) Also, do you get that error with any user or just with uname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay ... Upon installation of postgres another service was using the port 5432 so postgres took 5434. I didn't notice. Works now

Comment: Probably a previous Postgres instance had already taken 5432 (and another the 5433) port.

Comment: Yeah, some docker container exposing to this port, running another postgres instance. I just would have never assumed that it changes the standard port upon installation. I thought it would rather fail on startup! I know it is documented, but well ...